# how to make a method for dropdown in web services and to how call this method in web form

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api

I am making a method to for drop down throgh web services in which select query is used, my service run successfully but when I call my services method in web form of ASP.NET C# its gives error.

What am I missing?

```
        public void Route1()
        {
            Myservices.WebService1 objTest = new Myservices.WebService1();
            DataSet ret = objTest.GetDetialByID1();
            if (ret.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                DDL_Route.Items.Add(new ListItem(""));
                DDL_Route.AppendDataBoundItems = true;

                DDL_Route.DataTextField = "Route";
                DDL_Route.DataValueField = "Route_id";
                DDL_Route.DataBind();
            }
              else
           {
               lblMsg.Text = "Record not found";
           }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation, not only your code, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: i am making a method to for drop down throgh web services in which select query is used, my service run successfully but i when i call my services method in web form of asp.net  C# its gives error so please guide me

Comment: Place the text above in your question, everyone needs to know. Did you read the page already?

Comment: please provide more details about problem. what are type of error you getting?

Comment: my service method: using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_DropDownRoute", con))
                { cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            dt.TableName = "DDl_Route";
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the Dataset Tabel to Drop Down as follow

```
if (ret.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                  DDL_Route.DataSource = ret.Tables[0];
                  DDL_Route.DataTextField = "Route";
                  DDL_Route.DataValueField = "Route_id";
                  DDL_Route.DataBind();
            }
              else
           {
               lblMsg.Text = "Record not found";
           }
```